# Controller not registered - How to tell its path?

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I know what i'm missing but I don't know how to do it.

I structured my angular app by components like this :

```
app -> components -> home -> home.html homeController.js homeService.js
                  -> contact -> contact.html contactController.js contactService.js
app.js
index.html
```

in my app.js i use the common way to do it.

```
var appModule = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

appModule.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'components/home/home.html',
        controller  : 'homeController',
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : '/components/contact/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController',
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

My problem is that each controller isn't found.
I could define the html path with 'templateUrl', but I didn't find any controllerUrl ...

Thanks to share if you know how to do it :)

Comment: What do your controllers look like?

Comment: AngularJS uses dependency injection, so, give a route to the controller is not necessary. However, the controllers javascript files must be included in your html with a script tag

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to specify the controller path. Just reference your conntroller.js files on the index.html file.
angular will automatically load the controllers using the angular module under which it has been created.

index.html

```
<body>

 <script src="app/components/home/homecontroller.js"></script>
 <script src="app/components/contact/contactcontroller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a solution where I could avoid adding include in index by just referecing controller path, it works like this of course, thanks :)